# Sniff HTTP(S) from PPTP VPN server

Tags: tls, vpn, man-in-the-middle, android, http-proxy

I've setup an PPTP VPN server on my Debian 7 server. I'm using this VPN in combination with my Android phone to ensure a secure connection.

However, i'm getting curious of what my phone is sending and receiving, especially from Google. Is there a way to setup an HTTP(S) sniffer in my VPN server. I have some basic knowledge about sniffing (wireshark etc). I'm really curious what options are available to sniff http/https traffic thats flowing through my VPN?

Comment: You could crack the PPTP encryption. It's a very insecure protocol now.

Comment: What authentication are you using? You might want to look into some of Moxie Marlinspikes work.

Comment: I am currently looking for a way to do the same thing; I'm curious to see what options there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "burp" as a proxy which would enable you to see all http packets that you are receiving and sending.

It is pretty simple to use and works with pretty much everything. You can even edit/drop/resend packages.